# using groovy I need to analyze tags or nodes of xml file

Tags: python, xml, groovy

I've been trying to take an XML file from the server and go through the dates to try and see if my date value is the same as one of the xml date values. I am a little stuck because I am not to sure what to do after the xml file gets parsed. My code for the xml file and the script can be seen below;

XML file:

```
<holidays>
   <holiday type="fixed" name="New year's day" date="01/Jan" 
   duration_seconds="1d"/>
   <holiday type="fixed" name="Christmas day" date="25/Dec" 
   duration_seconds="1d"/>
   <holiday type="fixed" name="Boxing day" date="26/Dec" 
   duration_seconds="1d"/>
   <holiday type="floating" name="Family Day" date="20/Feb/17" 
   duration_seconds="1d"/>
   <holiday type="floating" name="Good Friday" date="14/Apr/17" 
   duration_seconds="1d"/>
   <holiday type="floating" name="CENGN Easter day off (only in 2017)" 
   date="17/Apr/17" duration_seconds="1d"/>
   <holiday type="floating" name="Victoria Day" date="22/May/17" 
   duration_seconds="1d"/>
   <holiday type="floating" name="Canada day" date="03/Jul/17" 
   duration_seconds="1d"/>
   <holiday type="floating" name="Civic Holiday" date="07/Aug/17" 
   duration_seconds="1d"/>
   <holiday type="floating" name="Labor day" date="04/Sep/17" 
   duration_seconds="1d"/>
  <holiday type="floating" name="Thanksgiving day" date="09/Oct/17" 
  duration_seconds="1d"/>
  </holidays>
```

And this is the script that I am trying to use.

```
    import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl;
    import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.customisers.PluginModule;
    import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.customisers.WithPlugin;
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager;
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
    import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager;
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue;
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.manager.OptionsManager
    import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl
    import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.customisers.PluginModule
    import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.customisers.WithPlugin
    import java.lang.Object
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.worklog.WorklogImpl2
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
    import com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User
    import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.worklog.DefaultWorklogManager
    import com.atlassian.jira.security.roles.ProjectRoleManager
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.worklog.Worklog
    import com.atlassian.jira.datetime.LocalDate
    import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils
    import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder 
    import groovy.util.*
    import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

    def componentManager = ComponentManager.getInstance()
    def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
    def cfend = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("End Date")
    def cfstart = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Start 
    Date")
    def cfdays = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Used 
    vacation days")
    def reporter = issue.reporter.name
    def worklogManager = ComponentAccessor.getWorklogManager();

    String f = new File('/var/atlassian/application-
    data/jira_7.3.1/import/holidays.xml')
    def list = new XmlParser().parse(f)

    def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(f)

    //NEED HELP AFTER THIS LINE ********************************

    def holiday = xml.depthFirst().findAll {it.holiday}
    xml.holiday.date() == 2

    def d =((issue.getCustomFieldValue(cfstart) as Date) + i).getDate() 
    def m = ((issue.getCustomFieldValue(cfstart) as Date) + i).getMonth() 

    return 0;
```

This is just a piece of my script and I am wondering if there is a good way to get the dates from the xml file and compare it to the issue date and issue month. I have trouble looking for examples of xml files that are similar to mine

Comment: Where is your expected date in the script which you want to compare against xml? Can the actual date from xml be in any tag?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I just saw your comment know. I actully just solved it. You can see the script on this page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573965/not-reading-the-xml-nodes-properly/44574836#44574836

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not reading the xml nodes properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573965/not-reading-the-xml-nodes-properly)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I bugged anybody. I just found the solution and I posted it on this page: 
[Not reading the xml nodes properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573965/not-reading-the-xml-nodes-properly/44574836#44574836)